# Flexbox: set child width to 80% while flex-direction is set to column on the parent

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

I am working on a React Native project. The container's `flexDirection` is set to `column` and I want the child's width to span 80% of the parent. If the parent's `flexDirection` was set to `row` I would have set the `flex` value to `0.8` and be done with it. The restrictions are

1. I can't have an additional container around the child.
2. I can't give the child a fixed width in pixels.

Here is a [playground](http://dabbott.github.io/react-native-web-player/#code=import%20React%2C%20%7B%20Component%20%7D%20from%20'react'%0Aimport%20%7B%0A%20%20AppRegistry%2C%0A%20%20StyleSheet%2C%0A%20%20Text%2C%0A%20%20View%2C%0A%20%20TouchableOpacity%0A%7D%20from%20'react-native'%0A%0Aclass%20App%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CView%20style%3D%7Bstyles.container%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%20style%3D%7Bstyles.cancel%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Cancel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FText%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20styles%20%3D%20StyleSheet.create(%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20flex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20'%23F5FCFF'%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20cancel%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20padding%3A%2010%2C%0A%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20'%23000'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20'%23FFF'%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)%0A%0AAppRegistry.registerComponent('App'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20App)%0A) to fiddle with the problem.

Comment: does `width:'80%'` not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently learned that after ReactNative version 0.42 there is support for percentage units not just only for width but also the following properties:

- `padding`
- `margin`
- `width`
- `height`
- `minWidth`
- `minHeight`
- `maxWidth`
- `maxHeight`
- `flexBasis`

If you want to learn more here is a [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/3f49e743bea730907066677c7cbfbb1260677d11) to the actual commit that added this awesome functionality.

The answer to my question would be to just add a percentage width of `80%`
Here it is my original [fiddle](http://dabbott.github.io/react-native-web-player/#code=import%20React%2C%20%7B%20Component%20%7D%20from%20'react'%0Aimport%20%7B%0A%20%20AppRegistry%2C%0A%20%20StyleSheet%2C%0A%20%20Text%2C%0A%20%20View%2C%0A%20%20TouchableOpacity%0A%7D%20from%20'react-native'%0A%0Aclass%20App%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CView%20style%3D%7Bstyles.container%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%20style%3D%7Bstyles.cancel%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Cancel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FText%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20styles%20%3D%20StyleSheet.create(%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20flex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20'%23F5FCFF'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20alignItems%3A%20'center'%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20cancel%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20padding%3A%2010%2C%0A%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20'%23000'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20'%23FFF'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%20'80%25'%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)%0A%0AAppRegistry.registerComponent('App'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20App)%0A) with the fix added.

Comment: As I figured. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can access screen dimensions with:

```
const {width, height} = require('Dimensions').get('window');
```

at your top level imports; then, in your style use:

```
child: {
   width: width*0.8
},
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thank you, I have considered this one and I would use it as a last resort if there is no way of doing is with flexbox only.